# DAX formula to subtract columns

Tags: dax, powerquery

I am trying to calculate month over month difference but it makes data negative.

I created a measure, but it makes source data negative.

[image: pivot]

```
CALCULATE (
        COUNTA ( SOURCE_DATA[COLUMN] ),
        FILTER ( SOURCE_DATA, SOURCE_DATA[YYYYMM] = "201906" )
    )
        - (
            CALCULATE (
                COUNTA ( SOURCE_DATA[COLUMN] ),
                FILTER ( SOURCE_DATA, SOURCE_DATA[YYYYMM] = "201905" )
            )
        )
```

The outcome is correct, but it changes data in previous month to negative.

Answer (score 0):

This is due to the filter context and the way you've written the measure.

Look at the visual table. For the field corresponding to Column = 201905 and row = GA you get -16 813. This is because the context of the visual table tells `CALCULATE` to `COUNTA(SOURCE_DATA[Column])` only when `MtM = GA` and  `Columns = 201905`. However, adding the `FILTER` you also tell `CALCULATE` to keep these criteria AND also make sure that `SOURCE_DATA[Column] = 201906` in the first calculate and 201905 in the second one.

This results in `CALCULATE` looking for rows where Column is both 201905 and 201906 at the same time. Or in other words you generate a venn diagram with no overlapping fields. Therefore the first calculate evaluates to 0 and the second to 16 813, so that the measure is actually evaluating 0-16813 = -16 813.

Since you didn't post any description of your data model I can inly guess what it looks like. However, since you're filtering on the SOURCE_DATA table I guess you don't use a Calendar table. This you should do! Have a calendar with a 1:* (1-to-many) relationship with the SOURCE_DATA and do filtering on the calendar. In addition you can have dynamically calculated day/week/month/year offsets so that you can create measures which don't have to be updated when there's a new month.

I think this video can be helpful: [sqlbi videolecture](https://www.sqlbi.com/tv/deep-dive-into-dax-evaluation-context/)

Also, have a look at this article: [sqlbi filter in calculate](https://www.sqlbi.com/articles/filter-arguments-in-calculate/)